# Can I define sub-clusters in dot language (Graphviz)?

Tags: graphviz, dot

In dot you can [define clusters](http://graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/cluster.html), which are basically boxes around a group of nodes. (1)

Is it possible to define a cluster, such that it is rendered *within* another cluster (a box within a box)?

(1) See also *Subgraphs and Clusters* in http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That works just fine:

```
graph {
    subgraph cluster1 
    {
        label="outside 1"
        subgraph cluster11
        {
            label="inside 1"
            a--b
        };
        subgraph cluster12
        {
            label="inside 2"
            c--d
        };
    };

    subgraph cluster2
    {
         label="outside 2"
         e--f
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: output with "outside" and "inside" clusters]